# Algorithm for fair distribution of revenue

Tags: algorithm, finance, discrete-mathematics

I am after an algorithm (preferably abstract or in very clear Python or PHP code) that allows for a fair distribution of revenue both in the short and in the long term, based on the following constraints:

1. Each incoming amount will be an integer.
2. Each distribution will be also an integer amount.
3. Each person in the distribution is set to receive a cut of the revenue expressed as a fixed fraction. These fractions can of course be put under a common denominator (think integer percentages with a denominator of 100). The sum of all numerators equals the denominator (100 in the case of percentages)
4. To make it fair in the short term, person `i` must be receiving either `floor(revenue*cut[i])` or `ceil(revenue*cut[i])`. **EDIT: Let me emphasize that `ceil(revenue*cut[i])` is not necessarily equal to `1+floor(revenue*cut[i])`, which is where some algorithms fail including one presented (see my comment on the answer by Andrey).**
5. To make it fair in the long term, as payments accumulate, the actual cuts received must be as close to the theoretical cuts as possible, preferably always under 1 unit. In particular, if the total revenue is a multiple of the denominator of the common fraction, every person should have received the corresponding multiple of their numerator.
6. [Edit] Forgot to add that the total amount distributed every time must of course add up to the incoming amount received.

Here's an example for clarity. Say there are three people among which to distribute revenue, and one has to get 31%, another has to get 21%, and the third has to get 100-31-21=48%.

Now imagine that there's an income of 80 coins. The first person should receive either `floor(80*31/100)` or `ceil(80*31/100)` coins, the second person should receive either `floor(80*21/100)` or `ceil(80*21/100)` and the third person, either `floor(80*48/100)` or `ceil(80*48/100)`.

And now imagine that there's a new income of 120 coins. Each person should again receive either the floor or the ceiling of their corresponding cuts, but since the total revenue (200) is a multiple of the denominator (100), each person should have now their exact cuts: the first person should have 62 coins, the second person should have 42 coins, and the third person should have 96 coins.

I think I have an algorithm figured out for the case of two people to distribute the revenue among. It goes like this (for 35% and 65%):

```
set TotalRevenue to 0
set TotalPaid[0] to 0
{ TotalPaid[1] is implied and not necessary for the algorithm }
set Cut[0] to 35
{ Cut[1] is implied and not necessary for the algorithm }
set Denominator to 100
each time a payment is received:
   let Revenue be the amount received this time
   set TotalRevenue = TotalRevenue + Revenue
   set tmp = floor(TotalRevenue*Cut[0]/Denominator)
   pay person 0 the amount of tmp - TotalPaid[0]
   set TotalPaid[0] = tmp
   pay person 1 the amount of TotalRevenue - TotalPaid[0]
```

I think that this simple algorithm meets all of my constraints, but I have not found the way to extend it to more than two people without violating at least one. Can anyone figure out an extension to multiple people (or perhaps prove its impossibility)?

Comment: Interesting problem... Are incoming amounts always distributed to the full set of people? And, if to the full set, can the cut percentages be adjusted between rounds (eg. person i gets 10% on one round but 17% on the next round)?

Comment: In my use case, always to the full set, and a change of percentages would mean a reset of the system: they can't be changed on the fly. I dind't want to complicate it that much.

Comment: Constraint 5 makes this problem sound like exactly the problem solved by the [Bresenham algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm): you want to draw a line in n dimensions, with one dimension per person; the line is drawn one pixel at a time, but in the long-term it must follow exactly the non-integer direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

- Keep track of a `totalReceived`, the total amount of money that has entered the system.
- When money is added to the system, add it to `totalReceived`.
- Set `person[i].newTotal = floor(totalReceived * cut[i])`.  **Edit: had error here; thanks commenters.**  This distributes some of the money.  Keep track of how much, to know how much "new money" is left over.  To be clear, we are keeping track of how much of the *total amount of money* is left over, and intuitively we re-distribute the whole sum at every step, although actually nobody's fund ever goes down between one step and the next.
- You need to know how to distribute the left-over integer amount of money: there should be less than `numPeople` amount left over.  For `i` ranging from `0` to `leftOverMoney - 1`, increment `person[i].newTotal` by 1.  Effectively we give a dollar to each of the first `leftOverMoney` people.
- To compute how much a person "received" during this step, compute `person[i].newTotal - person[i].total`.
- To clean/finish up, set `person[i].total = person[i].newTotal`.

Comment: For maximum fairness, distribute the remainder first to those people with the largest distribution error.  I.e. in step 3, also set person[i].error to fract(totalReceived * cut[i]).  Then in step 4, sort the people by .error, descending, before giving a coin to each of the first leftOverMoney people.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri You have to be careful that nobody's `newTotal` ends up being less than his `total` was if you make a modification like that.  And I think it's not obvious... in fact I think it's not true.

Comment: "Set person[i].newTotal = person[i].total + floor(totalReceived * cut[i])" is wrong.  If Pedro Gimeno attempts to use this calculation his distributed amounts will be much too large.  You are probably looking at "totalReceived" and thinking it represents the money added to the system for the current distribution.  But according to steps 1 and 2, it is the total money added to the system for all distributions so far, including the current distribution.

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know where you got this algorithm but it is spot on correct.  This is the method actually used by financial investment firms to distribute partial payments from a long-term fund.  As long as the partial payment is positive, and the values in cut[i] don't change, nobody's newTotal ends up being less than his total was.

Comment: I just came up with it.  Seems like the most obvious thing to do.

Comment: Without the modification in the first comment by A. I. Breveleri I think that the proposed algorithm can violate one of the constraints, namely that in each step everyone receives either the floor or the ceiling of the corresponding cut. Example: if the cuts are 20%, 37%, and 43%, and the incoming amount at start is 5, we have floor(5*20/100)=ceil(5*20/100)=1 and giving an additional coin to that person would violate the constraint. With the proposed modification of sorting by descending error, I'm not sure but it seems it might work. Can anyone comment on that?

Comment: @PedroGimeno nice counter-example.  I think that if you keep track of whether people are owed a fraction of a coin after the first step, and you just skip them in the "additional coin" step if they are not, then this will work.

Comment: The concern is then whether always number of people owed a fraction >= coins pending to distribute this round. Is that guaranteed to be the case? If not, then my requirements might prove impossible to satisfy. **EDIT** Of course it's guaranteed. The pending fractions are always less than 1 so their sum must be always less than the total amount to distribute. With that modification I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Um, it's not so obvious, after thinking about it again. My reasoning didn't apply to the algorithm you proposed; my head got confused. A proof that there will always be enough people with pending fractions as to receive the coins pending to distribute would be welcome.

Comment: I have a counterexample showing that this algorithm does not work. If the cuts are 31%, 59% and 10%, and the first payment is 9 coins, and the second payment is 1 coin, the person with 59% needs to *pay* 1 coin according to the algorithm because `person[i].newTotal` equals 6 the first time (5 plus an increase) and 5 the second time (because the product is still 5 and there's no increase the second time).

Comment: @Pedro Gimeno: You have applied the algorithm incorrectly. The remainder coins must be distributed to the investors in order from greatest to least distribution error. The integer distribution of the first payment of 9 coins results in Mr. 59% = 5 (error 0.31), Mr. 31% = 2 (error 0.79), and Mr. 10% = 0 (error 0.9), with 2 coins remaining. The 2 coins are then awarded to Mr. 10% and Mr. 31% because their errors are greater than Mr. 59%'s. The final distribution of 9 coins is thus Mr 59% = 5, Mr. 31% = 3, and Mr. 10% = 1.

Comment: @Pedro Gimeno: Similarly, the second payment of 1 coin brings the total payments to 10 coins, distributed as Mr. 59% = 5 (error 0.9), Mr. 31% = 3 (error 0.1), and Mr. 10% = 1 (error 0), with 1 coin remaining. This remaining coin is awarded to the investor with the greatest distribution error, Mr. 59%. The final distribution of 10 coins is thus Mr 59% = 6, Mr. 31% = 3, and Mr. 10% = 1. The fund cuts a check to Mr. 59% for 1 coin; Mr. 31% and Mr. 10% get nothing from the second payment. Nobody is ever required to pay back any money.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri: I applied the algorithm as it appears in Andrey Mishchenko's answer, which does not have that extra step. The answer as stated does not work. I haven't evaluated the algorithm with your change included, but I will if you add it as an answer, or if Andrey modifies the answer with that step added, and accept it if it works.

Comment: @Pedro Gimeno: I agree. You are correct. Your counterexample causes Andrey's algorithm without the distribution error ordering to fail. \ FWIW in real life the *unmodified* algorithm has been in use for decades, to round dividends to even dollars, without causing a clawback problem because (1) payments are very large compared to the number of investors and (2) the automatic calculation is always followed by a manual review and adjustment step anyway, where clawback is just one of many problems to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

To accomodate constraint 4, the current payment must be used as the basis for distribution. After distributing the rounded dividends to the investors, the leftover dollars may be awarded, one each, to any eligible investors. An investor is eligible if he is due a fractional share, that is, ceil(revenuecut[i]) > floor(revenuecut[i]).

Constraint 5 may be addressed by deciding who, among the eligible investors, should get the leftover dollars. Maximum long-term fairness will be most closely approached by always awarding the leftover dollars to the eligible investors who have accumulated the most total (long-term) distribution error.

The following is derived from the algorithm I used for my fund manager clients. (I always used Pascal for financial applications for forensic reasons.) I have transposed the code fragments from a database application to an array-based method in an attempt to improve the clarity.

Included in the accounting data structures is a table of investors. Included in the information about each investor is his share fraction (investor share count divided by fund total shares), amount earned to date, and amount distributed (actually paid to investor) to date.

```
Investors : array [0..InvestorCount-1] of record
        // ... lots of information about this investor
        ShareFraction       : float; // >0 and <1
        EarnedToDate        : currency; // rounded to dollars
        DistributedToDate   : currency; // rounded to dollars
    end;
// The sum of all the .ShareFraction in the table is exactly 1.
```

Some temporary data is created for these calculations and freed afterwards.

```
DistErrs : array [0..InvestorCount-1] of record
        TotalError      : float; // distribution rounding error
        CurrentError    : float; // distribution rounding error
        InvestorIndex   : integer; // link to Investors record
    end;
UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS  : currency;
CurrentFloat            : float;
CurrentInteger          : currency;
CurrentFraction         : float;
TotalFloat              : float;
TotalInteger            : currency;
TotalFraction           : float;
DD, II                  : integer; // array indices
```

`FUND_PREVIOUS_PAYMENTS : currency;` is a parameter, derived from the fund history. If it is not provided as a parameter it may be calculated as the sum over all Investors[].EarnedToDate.

`FUND_CURRENT_PAYMENT : currency;` is a parameter, derived from the current increase in fund value.

`FUND_TOTAL_PAYMENTS : currency;` is a parameter, derived from the current fund value. This is the fund total amount previously paid out plus the fund current payment.

These three values form a dependents system with two degrees of freedom. Any two may be provided and the third calculated from the others.

```
// Calculate how much each investor has earned after the fund current payment.
UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS := FUND_CURRENT_PAYMENT;
for II := 0 to InvestorCount-1 do begin

  // Calculate theoretical current dividend whole and fraction parts.
  CurrentFloat := FUND_CURRENT_PAYMENT * Investors[II].ShareFraction;
  CurrentInteger := floor(CurrentFloat);
  CurrentFraction := CurrentFloat - CurrentInteger;

  // Calculate theoretical total dividend whole and fraction parts.
  TotalFloat := FUND_TOTAL_PAYMENTS * Investors[II].ShareFraction;
  TotalInteger := floor(TotalFloat);
  TotalFraction := TotalFloat - TotalInteger;

  // Distribute the current whole dollars to the investor.
  Investors[II].EarnedToDate := Investors[II].EarnedToDate + CurrentInteger;
  // Track total whole dollars distributed.
  UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS := UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS - CurrentInteger;

  // Record the fractional dollars in the errors table and link to investor.
  DistErrs[II].CurrentError := CurrentFraction;
  DistErrs[II].TotalError := TotalFraction;
  DistErrs[II].InvestorIndex := II;

end;
```

At this point `UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS` is always less than `InvestorCount`.

```
// Sort DistErrs by .TotalError descending.
```

In the real world the data is kept in a database not in arrays, so sorting is done by creating an index on `DistErrs` using `TotalError` as a key.

```
// Distribute one dollar each to the first UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS eligible 
// investors (i.e. those whose current share ceilings are higher than their 
// current share floor), in order from greatest to least .TotalError.
for DD := 0 to InvestorCount-1 do begin
if UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS <= 0 then break;
  if DistErrs[DD].CurrentError <> 0 then begin
    II := DistErrs[DD].InvestorIndex;
    Investors[II].EarnedToDate := Investors[II].EarnedToDate + 1;
    UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS := UNDISTRIBUTED_PAYMENTS - 1;
  end;
end;
```

In a subsequent process, each investor is paid the difference between his `.EarnedToDate` and his `.DistributedToDate`, and his `.DistributedToDate` is adjusted to reflect that payment.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Regrettably, this algorithm doesn't satisfy the constraints either. To rule out float rounding problems, I've tried with 32 shares, with first investor having 3, second investor having 7, and third investor having 32-3-7=22. Then two payments: first 379, then 244. In the last payment the 4th constraint is violated, as it pays 24 coins to the first investor when the correct value should be between 22 and 23 (real value is 22.875). Here's my program: http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/pastes/invest.py

Comment: I've made it work by adding a loop that enforces the 4th constraint before the final loop. That obviates the need of sorting, and with it the need for a `DistErrs` array. I haven't cleaned it up to get rid of it, though, to keep it as close to your code and my previous code as possible, to highlight the differences. I haven't proved it always works, but I couldn't find a case where it fails. Here's the code: http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/pastes/invest-fixed.py

Comment: I've modified my algorithm to meet your constraint 4 while most closely approaching your constraint 5. In the last loop, skipping any investor with CurrentError = 0 avoids violating his ceiling, and pre-ordering by TotalError descending maximizes long-term fairness.

Comment: I've tested your modified algorithm. It still fails constraint 5. With 3/32, 7/32 and 22/32 as before, a payment of 82 followed by a payment of 263 causes the 3rd investor to receive an accumulated value of 236, when they should have received 237.1875. OTOH, a first pay of 404 followed by 19 causes the 3rd investor to have received 292, when they should have received 290.8125. I think that the best operative definition of "as close as possible" for constraint 5 is "between floor and ceil" aka "less than 1 coin off". My modified algorithm above seems to prove it's possible to do so.

Comment: Here's my program, in case I made a mistake:http://www.formauri.es/personal/pgimeno/pastes/invest-new.py